# :before content taking up space differently in windows/mac Chrome

Tags: css, macos, google-chrome

There's a slight difference between the way Chrome for Windows and Chrome for Mac handle content added in CSS to :before.

Here's the CSS for the following:

```
.s-smiley:before {
  content: "\EA20";
}

 .s-smiley {
  color: white;
  background: #D8D8D8;
  margin-top: 46px;
  margin-right: 16px;
  padding: 9px;
  font-size: 37px;
  line-height: 29px;
}
 .s-smiley {
  background: #50E3C2;
}

.s:before {
    display: inline-block;
    font-family: symbols;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    line-height: 37px;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

The issue is that in Windows - the content seems to be pushed down and also takes up room. Anyone else know this issue? Is there a fix for it?

Chrome for Windows:

[image: Chrome for Windows]

Chrome for Mac:

[image: Chrome for Mac]

Comment: add a display type for before, for example display:block with height and width declared

Comment: @VictorRadu - sorry I missed a line of CSS - I have the :before set as an inline-block. But it doesn't help. Even if I do block, and set the height, it just cuts off the bottom of the font instead of bumping it back up.

Answer (score 0):

hard to say without complete code but try this:

```
.s:before {
    display: block;
    float:left;
    font-family: symbols;
    font-style: normal;
    font-weight: 400;
    height: 37px;
    line-height:37px;
    overflow:hidden;
    -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
    -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/kmrjy11d/

also make sure your font files are correct